# How to use Node.js to serve an HTML page which then writes data to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a noob with NodeJS and I'm struggling to understand how NodeJS, HTML, and JavaScript interact...

I have an HTML file which I serve using NodeJS. In the HTML there is a bunch of JavaScript code that takes in a users input and assembles an object. Now I want to write this object to a JSON file.

Here is the cut-down HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MetaFlex</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wholePage" class="container-fluid">...
    </div>

    <script>
        // global dictionary object
        let dictionaryObject = [];

        $(document).ready(function () {

        ... get user input, do some stuff, add results to dictionaryObject ...

            // write the dictionary to a JSON file
            writeDictionary();
    });

        // write object to JSON file
        function writeDictionary() {
            var fs = require("fs");

            fs.writeFile("./dictionaryObject.json", JSON.stringify(dictionaryObject, null, 4), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                };
                console.log("File has been created");
            });
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and here is the server code (app.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
var filename = "." + q.pathname;
fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
});
}).listen(8080);
```

I serve the HTML by:

1. starting the server with the command line: 
   node app
2. load the page: http://localhost:8080/metaFlex.html

The page displays, I can enter data which is written to dictionaryObject...

But when the JS gets to the "require" function I get the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at writeDictionary (metaFlex.html:1286)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (metaFlex.html:1220)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I feel that I must be missing some critical piece of the puzzle.... Am I missing an include at the top of the HTML ? Do I need to split the HTML file into its HTML and JS components ? Should I give up on my crazy JSON dream and write a plain ol' local text file ? Is it true that you can't teach an old dog new tricks ? *le sigh*

You love and guidance steering me back onto the path would be much appreciated !

Comment: Do you want this json file to be stored on the server, or on the client computer?

Comment: instead of the code, you mind posting your requirement first. both in terms of the application as well in terms of the user

Comment: For the moment, I'm trying to write any file (local or server-side). Ultimately, the file written will be on the server so that people can load the page from the Internet and the data written out will be persistent and available to the web page for reload.

Comment: With respect to my requirements, I'm writing an app that allows people to add to a dictionary of terms, or search through a dictionary of already added terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use json in the server side with nodejs , and instead of writing in the client , you can use AJAX to add terms , 
you need to use routes in your server , not just serving html like that , 
if the dictionary is common for all client that will the best solution 
if every client has a specific dictionnary you can add an identifier for each file (Dictionnary)

Comment: So basically, once I have assembled the object that I want to write, I would use a XMLHttpRequest to pass that data to a "write" function running on the server ?

Comment: yes that's correct ,, so the file will be in the server

Comment: you need to add a route app.post(("/addWord",function(req,res){/*code here */}) .... and here you can write in the json file

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction ! Based on your suggestion I was able to find the following video that explained all the coding necessary: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82hnvUYY6QA

Comment: I guess I should have said the video helps me with the AJAX code details...  The video helped me to understand how to set up the XMLHttpRequest object and pass a var. Now I'm on a mission to hook that into a node.js write so that I can actually create the JSON file.

Comment: use the routes in your server

Comment: this is how to set up routes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiMLxUKrB-g